# How do I insert a line in a file to the beginning of a file in Perl?

Tags: perl

I used a Perl helper to code this. It
looks I am missing a character or something.
I need to write the new text to the top of the text file.

```
open (LOGFILE, ">> complete.txt") ; # writes new to the bottom

$datetime = localtime ;

print LOGFILE "\n" ;

print LOGFILE $datetime\n" ;
print LOGFILE "$name\n" ;
print LOGFILE "Has completed the work\n" ;

close (LOGFILE) ;
```

Comment: That looks fine so far, you should get into more detail. What is your problem? There is a missing " before $datetime in line 4, maybe that is the cause ...

Comment: You need to rewrite the file: open new file, write text, copy previous file contents, close files, rename new file as old.

Comment: @ tex, i don't know if a " is missing. could you please specify, thanks..

Comment: `sed` might be a bit easier for this. `sed -i "$datetime\n$name\nHas completed the work" complete.txt`, assuming you have those variables defined.

Answer (score 8):

This is answered in the [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-faq.html).

[How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?)

If you're programming in Perl, then it's well worth taking an hour or so to skim the FAQ. It's full of useful information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Tie::File` module to enable access to the file via an array:

```
use Tie::File;
my @array;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', 'complete.txt' or die $!;
unshift @array, localtime."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the quick answers, was only a few minutes ago. 
This seems to work great

it is what pascal recomended, I just did'nt know how to do that.

```
open (LOGFILE, "complete.txt") ;
@data = ;
close (LOGFILE);

open (LOGFILE, ">complete.txt") ;

$datetime = localtime ; 

print LOGFILE "\n" ; 

print LOGFILE $datetime\n" ; 
print LOGFILE "$name\n" ; 
print LOGFILE "Has completed the work\n" ; 

foreach (@data) {
    print LOGFILE $_;
}

close (LOGFILE) ;
```